# Lagrange multipliers/multivariable optimisation problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Problem:
>
> Maximise the volume $V$ of a cuboid shaped box with closed top, fixed surface area $S$, and side lengths $x, y,$ and $z$

What I've got so far:

$V=xyz$, $S=2(xy+yz+zx)$, $\nabla V = \lambda \nabla P$

and so

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\partial V / \partial x =\lambda\ \partial g / \partial x \\ 
\partial V / \partial y =\lambda\ \partial g / \partial y \\ 
\partial V / \partial z =\lambda\ \partial g / \partial z \\
S =2(xy+yz+zx)
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

i.e. 
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
yz =2\lambda\ (y+z) \\ 
xz =2\lambda\ (x+z)\\ 
xy =2\lambda\ (x+y) \\
S =2(xy+yz+zx)
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

How do I solve this set of equations? Elimination and matrix methods didn't work. And how could I extrapolate this problem to

1. a box with no lid?
2. A closed box of variable shape (i.e. prove the sphere has the lowest surface area to volume ratio)?
3. A box in higher dimensions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
yz =2\lambda\ (y+z) \ \quad \color{blue}{(I)} \\ 
xz =2\lambda\ (x+z) \quad \color{blue}{(II)} \\ 
xy =2\lambda\ (x+y) \quad \color{blue}{(III)} \\
S =2(xy+yz+zx) \quad \color{blue}{(IV)}
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

**Hint**: Divide $(I)$ by $(II)$. Then multiply both sides by the denominators (in brackets). Then you can multiply out the brackets. You will see the relation between x and y, if $z \neq 0$. I hope you can go on from here.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve the equations, getting x=y=z and so $S=6x^2$ and $V=x^3$ (as expected). For the additional questions, I think I've got 1) (answer posted below) but i'm still not sure how I'd generalise the shape for 2)? And for 3), would it work to just add more variables?

Answer (score 0):

1. A box with no lid?

The equations become
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
yz =\lambda\ (y+2z) \\ 
xz =\lambda\ (x+2z)\\ 
xy =2\lambda\ (x+y) \\
S = xy+2yz+2zx
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

giving for the maximum: $x=y=2z$ and so $S=3x^2, V=x^3/2$